# Is it safe to commit, branch and amend at original branch?

Tags: git

It it safe to commit at branch A, branch a new branch B, amend last commit at A, leaving B with the new commit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Amending a commit changes the tag of that commit. So branch B will have a new commit that branch A doesn't have and branch A will have a new commit that branch B doesn't have in this case. If you merge branch B back into A with a simple merge, your log in branch A will look like:

```
*    Merge from Branch B
|\  
| *  a change from Branch B
| *  commit related to xxx
* |  Amended commit related to xxx
|/  
*  Last commit before branching
```

Comment: so, it's seems there're no problems, it's safe.

Comment: But if you merge Branch B into Branch A, you will have two logs for the same amended commit(the old one and the amended one) which doesn't look good.

Comment: In truth, I've made the wrong question =/, sorry. It was not about amending, It's about undo a commit (or more than one) in A. Reseting to a previous commit. To delete some tail history from A and let it in B.

Comment: That would totally change the answer, maybe you can ask that as a new question.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14380618/is-it-safe-to-commit-branch-and-undo-at-original-branch

Answer (score 0):

If you are not going to merge Branch B into Branch A then you have to ensure that the change you made in Branch A is moved to Branch B also unless you freeze Branch B.