# Is it safe to commit, branch and undo at original branch?

Tags: git

It it safe to commit at branch A, branch a new branch B, undo last commit (or more) at A (resetting to a previous commit), leaving B with history that was deleted from A?

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: @me_and I know no problem will happen at trial moment, the point is about safety in future merges or other related problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To clarify your example, you currently have this:

```
Z-Y-X-W  <--A
```

And you'd like to branch B where A currently is, so you'll have this:

```
Z-Y-X-W  <--A,B
```

And then revert A to an earlier point

```
Z-Y  <--A
   \
    X-W <--B
```

Yes, you can do this.  Branches are just pointers to a commit, so you can move them around willy nilly.   As long as a commit has a branch pointing to it, it will stay in your repository for future use.  Remove the last brach pointing to it, and it will be garbage collected.

But another important question:   is A tracking a remote branch origin/A?  If so, you need to be much more careful not to alter the history of origin/A.

Comment: Thanks, and no, this only local rearrangement.